# Which is the best way to check (with some certainty) if the mean of a time series is a constant?

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing

I am testing the time series output by a light sensor, and trying to know when dawn and dusk end. I used a cusum test to check when light level starts changing, and now I need to know when it stabilizes to a constant level (night or day).

I learned about student tests and p_values. The problem is that in the examples I found, the null hypothesis is always that the slope of the linear regression is zero, but I need the opposite: the null hypothesis should be that the slope is non-zero, so I can conclude with certain confidence that my time series is constant (slope = 0)

Is there a way that I can change the null hypothesis for the alternate one?
Or is there a better way to check if the sensor output is constant?

(By the way, I am working in python)

Comment: A constructive, practical approach might eschew hypothesis tests altogether and focus instead on the consequences of your decision making. Why do you need to make a determination of the day/night terminator? What would it cost you to make a later decision than is correct? What would be the cost of an incorrect earlier decision? You could then optimize your expected loss with an appropriate decision procedure. As a technical matter, it would be good to know if the sensor has any "carryover" or "memory" effects leading to autocorrelation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test for a mean (intercept) of a time series being constant requires that you account for any ARIMA structure and of course any pulses/seasonal pulses and any non-constant error variance. If the adjusted Y i.e. the errors from an ARIMA model evident a level shift this would be found via Intervention Detection procedures. If the ARIMA model contains a differencing operator/factor or a near non-stationary AR factor this is equivalent to testing the hypothesis of a constant intercept.

Comment: You are more than welcome.